# writeToFile not working in Swift 2.0 project

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, swift2

I am trying to save an NSMutableArray to the local storage on the device. To do that I followed a tutorial and ended up with this code:

```
func saveResolutions() {
        let pathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory = pathsArray[0] as String
        let savePath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("resolution_list.plist")
        resolutionItems.writeToFile(savePath, atomically: true)
        
        print("Saved")
    }
    
    func loadResolutions() {
        let pathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory = pathsArray[0] as String
        let resolutionListPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("resolution_list.plist")
        
        if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(resolutionListPath){
            resolutionItems = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: resolutionListPath)!
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
        
        print("Loading Data From Storage")
    }
```

To clarify this, in order to be able to use `stringByAppendingPathComponents`I used an SO posts answer to extend String, with the code below:

```
extension String {
    
    func stringByAppendingPathComponent(path: String) -> String {
        
        let nsSt = self as NSString
        
        return nsSt.stringByAppendingPathComponent(path)
    }
```

In the sample project, this works without a problem. It saves to the file and then on the next launch loads it up. However when I tried to implement this it wasn't working at all. Therefore, I decided to check if the file exists as soon as it gets saved. To achieve that I'm using:

```
let pathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory = pathsArray[0] as String
        let resolutionListPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("resolution_list.plist")
    print(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(resolutionListPath))
```

While this should logically print `true` immediately after saving (that's when I run it) it prints `false`. I tried restarting Xcode, clearing the derived data, resetting the simulator, but nothing seemed to help here. It's still returning `false`

Comment: You should get used to NSURL file paths instead of casting to  NSString.

Comment: you should provide an extension for your file name. It is not a directory

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that first thing in the morning,

Comment: Would I read the same way then? But weirdly it's working for the second project...

Comment: you can access your NSURL.path instead of just a string path